# Issue with javascript classes and mouse clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm trying to classify my javascript code.

I have a class called node, which simply contains an integer, a label element to display that integer, and a button element to increment the integer.

When I call the `incrementInteger` function via code, everything works as expected. But when I try to use a mouse click event listener to call the `incrementInteger` function, things do not work.

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var firstNode = new Node();
    firstNode.incrementInteger();
    var secondNode = new Node();
});

function Node() {
    this.integer = 0;
    this.incrementInteger = function() {
        this.integer++;
        this.label.innerHTML = this.integer;
    }
    this.addButton = document.createElement("button");
    this.addButton.addEventListener("mousedown", this.incrementInteger);
    this.container = document.createElement("div");
    this.label = document.createElement("div");
    this.label.innerHTML = this.integer;

    var bodyElement = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
    this.container.appendChild(this.label);
    this.container.appendChild(this.addButton);
    bodyElement.appendChild(this.container);
}
```

Comment: If you are using jQuery, why do all the DOM related stuff with vanilla JS?

Comment: Either of the two answers below will work (they are different and one might work better for you than the other), but see [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) as to why. Short version is that 'this' is set based on calling context.

Comment: Thanks peterjb, after I saw the solution, I was curious why it worked, and mine did not, and your comment helped resolve my confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` inside your `incrementInteger` function does not refer to the property on the object. Create a context reference:

```
var self = this;
this.integer = 0;
this.incrementInteger = function() {
    self.integer++;
    self.label.innerHTML = self.integer;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/0bgjpp4w

Comment: Thanks a ton for the quick response, and the jsfiddle. This completed solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should be binding the `this` to your `incrementInteger` like this:

```
this.incrementInteger = function() {
    this.integer++;
    this.label.innerHTML = this.integer;
}.bind(this);
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I gave tymeJV the answer because he answered first, but yours was helpful as well. I don't have enough rep to upvote yet, but when I do, I'll make sure to upvote this.

Answer (score 0):

If your `incrementInteger()` is identical for each and every 'node'-object created with your 'Node' constructor, then it should probably be a `prototype`! Otherwise (in plain vanilla javascript) you wouldn't have *shared* methods (and properties).

Using `addEventListener` you *almost* got it right, yet you passed the object's local function *instead of the object itself* (thereby losing the correct reference to `this` as explained in other answers).

The idea is that `addEventListener` can take an *object as a second argument* that will look for a method called [`handleEvent`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-EventListener-handleEvent) and call it!
No need for binding `this`; it will pass around the context correctly: the context is the object you’ve just set as the event listener callback.

That gives us the means to move the (otherwise repetitively cloned) `incrementInteger` function to the constructor's `prototype`, including the `handleEvent` function.  *NICE*!

```js
function Node(){ 
    this.integer = 0;
    this.addButton = document.createElement('button');
    this.addButton.addEventListener('mousedown', this);
    this.container = document.createElement('div');
    this.label = document.createElement('div');
    this.label.innerHTML = this.integer;
    this.container.appendChild(this.label);
    this.container.appendChild(this.addButton);
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(this.container);
}

Node.prototype={
  incrementInteger: function(){
    this.integer++;
    this.label.innerHTML = this.integer;
  },
  handleEvent: function(){  // track event source-element to overload functionality.
    this.incrementInteger();  
  }
};

// avoiding the html jquery script load line for this snippet
window.onload=function(){          // $(document).ready(function() {
    var firstNode = new Node();
    firstNode.incrementInteger();
    var secondNode = new Node();
};                                 // });
```

---

**Edit:**

Alternatively (for example) you could write this simply as:

```js
(window.Node = function(){
  var d=document;
  this.container  = d.createElement('div');
  (this.label     = this.container.appendChild(d.createElement('div'))
  ).innerHTML     = this.integer = 0;
  (this.addButton = this.container.appendChild(d.createElement('button'))
  ).addEventListener('mousedown', this);
  d.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(this.container);
}).prototype={
  incrementInteger: function(){
    this.label.innerHTML = ++this.integer;
  }
, handleEvent: function(){  
    this.incrementInteger();
  }
};


window.onload=function(){
    var firstNode = new Node();
    firstNode.incrementInteger();
    var secondNode = new Node();
};
```

Above, you can see we used (in code) the identifier `Node` just once, so there is just one place to rename your identifier.
Every method (or property) that the objects (created by the constructor) share are easily visible under the `prototype`.
Apart from ES6 Classes, this is the closest you can get in pure javascript to implement what you (seem) to intend: one code-block with one identifier describing the *unique* and *shared* sections of your 'class' (since 'common' javascript doesn't have classes!).

Or (for example) making private stuff available (shared) *to the constructor only* (a third section) using a closure:
(also re-factored constructor-code to just 2 lines while retaining all functionality intended in your original code.)

```js
(function(ns){
 var b = document, d = b.createElement('div');
 (b = b.createElement('button')).innerHTML = 'Click me';
  
 (ns.Node = function(){
   (this.label     = (this.container = d.cloneNode(false)
                     ).appendChild( d.cloneNode(false) )
   ).innerHTML     = this.integer = 0;
   (this.addButton = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]
                             .appendChild( this.container )
                             .appendChild( b.cloneNode(true) )
   ).addEventListener('mousedown', this);
 }).prototype={
   incrementInteger: function(){ this.label.innerHTML = ++this.integer; }
 ,      handleEvent: function(){ this.incrementInteger(); }
 };
})(window); // pass namespace to hook object-creator 'Node' to.


window.onload=function(){
    var firstNode = new Node();
    firstNode.incrementInteger();
    var secondNode = new Node();
};
```